# Invalid syntax error of Python 3's str.split in Python 2

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, split

The below line works fine for me in python3. How can I fix it for python 2.

```
word, *vector = line.split()
```

Error in Python 2:

> ```
> word, *vector = line.split()
>       ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick without polluting the namespace...

```
word, vector = (lambda x,*y:(x, y))(*line.split())
```

however I don't think many Python programmers would love it

Comment: Seems needlessly complex and a bit overkill.

Comment: @JamesShapiro: unfortunately Python does not provide local scopes except for function bodies and there are brains for which names are more of an issue compared to nesting (I know because I'm one of those cases). In my solution there are no extra names involved (except for the short-lived `x` and `y`, that you can forget about right after reading them). In your solution there is `arr`... was it used before and is overwritten? will be used later?  I cannot really know what your code really does without analyzing the whole function body.

Comment: Another alternative would be writing line.split() twice.

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
arr = line.split()
word = arr[0]
vector = arr[1:]
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution:

```
import re
word, vector = re.split('', line)[0], re.split('', line)[1:]
```

Comment: word, vector = line.split()[0], line.split()[1:] should also work. Better to avoid importing re if you don't need it and it's not simplifying your code.